# Show hours pr day in a given interval example below

Tags: .net, datetime

I want to have a dynamic .net function which takes a parameter called duration and lists all the hours of a day with that given duration.
E.g. if i have a duration of 90 minutes I want my out put to be

```
00:00
01:30
03:00 
....
22:30
```

and if the duration is 15
it should be

```
00:00
00:15
00:30
...
23.45
```

how would your take be on crafting this.
Let me know if you have any further questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple while loop should suffice ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aEYHKt)):

```
public static void Main()
{
    foreach (var t in GetTimesOfDay(new TimeSpan(0, 90, 0)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.ToString(@"hh\:mm"));
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetTimesOfDay(TimeSpan distance)
{
    var t = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    var fullDay = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
    
    while (t < fullDay)
    {
        yield return t;
        t = t.Add(distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, works perfect... apparently I over analyzed it in my head!